# How to fix Error: id must be a 15 character

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, id

Hi I have developed a custom lookup field in the VF page, The feild is when we enter any string it will show a drop down list with the similar Account names.

When I choose My account name and Hit Next page it throws the following Error.

[image]

Here is My controller Associated with this field - Group.
VF:

```
 <apex:outputPanel >
      <apex:outputText ><b>Group</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</apex:outputText>
      <apex:inputText value="{!order.Group__c}" onkeypress="genlist.call($(this));" styleClass="inpacc"/>
      <apex:inputText value="{!GroupLookUp}" styleClass="dummy"/>
      <div class="drpdwnlist"></div>
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

Apex:

```
public NewOrderController()
{
  order = new order(); 
    orderlist = [Select Id, Group__r.name,Group__c,order.Account.Name from Order];
}
@RemoteAction public static string accsearch(string sample)
{
        String qstring = '%'+sample+'%';
        string resultstring = '';
        list<Account> srchacclist = [Select Id,Name,Type,ParentId from Account Where Name like:qstring];

        for(Account a :srchacclist)
            resultstring+=a.Name+'%'+a.Id+'#';
        return resultstring;
  }
```

Please advise.

Comment: what is the value of GroupLookUp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code listing is incomplete, so it isn't possible to be sure what is happening.  However, the error indicates that the value DAVS122 is being assigned to an ID, which isn't valid.  I'm guessing that the value has been typed into the `apex:inputText value="{!order.Group__c}"` and the keypress handler has been invoked.  It's also evident from the query in your apex that Order.Group__c is a lookup field.  `apex:inputText` doesn't really work with Lookup fields, which need IDs and not text.

Are you are trying to lookup the value "DAVS122" within the Group__c sObject?  Change the `apex:inputText` to `apex:inputField`.  Then VF will provide the "lookup" functionality to convert object names to IDs automatically - just like the Account input above.

Comment: I have made that changed , Actually iam not looking for the lookup so I made  the change from order.Group__c to order.Group__r.name and i was able eliminate that error.

Comment: Please add an answer explaining the resolution, and accept that answer so that others who find this question can benefit.  Or if you believe this answer addresses the question, you can accept it.